# How to change the path to the installation disk image in VirtualBox?

Tags: virtualbox

I made a stupid mistake when setting up a new VM by accepting the default path to the installation media (`D:`). Of course, it failed to boot.

When I restart it, it does not re-prompt me for the media, and I cannot find any options to change it. I also haven't had any luck finding anything online, everyone else is asking how to move the the VDI file, which isn't what I want.

I'd prefer to not have to re-setup and re-create everything when I should just have to change one path. Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the `devices -> optical drives` menu:

[image]